# what is the correct expression of the two below?

Tags: expressions

Is is right to say "I have a pen" or  "I am having a pen" ?  I keep hearing people using the latter.

Comment: It depends on the variety of English. In area where Indian English does not predominate, the progressive _be having_ is only used in very limited circumstances: experiencing a state,(I'm having a bad day) or planning an event (I'm having a party). But I have noticed that Indian English makes much more general use of the progressive with verbs like _have_ and _know_ than other varieties of English.

Answer (score 1):

"I have a pen" is the correct way to show possession of an object.

"I am having" is used mostly for a state of being, such as

"I am having a bad day"

or

"I am having trouble with this math test"

or

"I am having a heart attack"

Comment: Note that there is no real difference between *I am having a pen*, *I am having a heart attack*, *I am having sadness*, and *I am having dinner*. But only the second and fourth of those would we deem correct. This is an annoyance. It's more about usage than it really is about logic. What you say is *generally* true, but it's also something that, unfortunately, has to be learned through experience. (And if you are eating  a pen for dinner, you actually *can* be "having a pen." ;)